# Puede una tabla relacional estar conectada 2 veces a otra tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una base de datos y se gustaría saber, si es posible y tiene sentido a nivel de base de datos y estructura, que la tabla de lenguas esté conectada 2 veces a la tabla alumPosgrado como llaves foráneas y a su vez esa tabla de lenguas esté conectada a una tabla de tareas.

El propósito de estas uniones es que cuando se indique el lenguaje de la tarea, ésta pueda ser mostrada al alumno que tenga el mismo idioma que la tarea en su front. El asunto de ponerle 2 id de lenguaje al alumPosgrado es porque un alumno está inscrito en 2 lenguajes a la vez y la tarea puede ser en un lenguaje u otro.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si. Así que un alumno siempre tiene dos lenguas, son dos relaciones independientes a la tabla de lenguas (dos foreign keys). Y si, una tarea también tiene una relación a la tabla de lenguas. El modelo me parece correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, una tabla puede estar conectada a otra las veces que la semántica lo requiera. Pero no exactamente como intentas modelar. Por lo que comentas, tu modelo ER sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que los alumnos hablarán las lenguas que hayan aprendido: 1, 2 o las que sean. Y, si hablan una lengua, podrán entender todas las tareas que hayan sido redactadas en esa lengua. Como todas esas cardinalidades son N:M, vas a necesitas más tablas que las implementadas en tu ejemplo.

Con esta consulta obtendrías el listado de alumnos que podrían realizar una determinada tarea:

```
SELECT id_alumno FROM redactan
  JOIN hablan USING(id_lengua)
  WHERE id_tarea=1;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y seguiremos puliendo el modelo.

Comment: El caso de la base de datos es que un alumno se inscribe en 1 posgrado de traduccion, y a la hora de registrarse el alumno tiene que elegir 2 lenguajes (hacia un lenguaje o desde un lenguaje) en los que va a traducir durante el curso las tareas que reciba. Entonces cuando recibe un tarea, está en uno de los 2 idiomas en los que se ha registrado, nunca en los 2 a la vez, y es el admin quien determina el idioma de la tarea. Por ello planteaba si podría estar conectada la tabla lengua 2 veces a AlumPosgrado y 1 vez a la tabla tareas, para poder comprobar si la id es la misma en ambos casos.

Comment: La respuesta corta es sí pero, si dudas, igual es mejor que lo hablemos. Contacta conmigo a través del enlace a linkedin que tienes en mi perfil y lo comentamos con calma